# return alphanumeric values from column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe df.  it has 2 columns like the example input shown below.  I would like to create a new output dataframe, with a new column 'col3' that only has the alphanumeric values from the strings in col2.

I've tried using spark sql with

```
regexp_extract('('+col1+')','[^[A-Za-z0-9] ]', 0)
```

but it only returns null.

can anyone suggest how to do this?

input

```
df.show()


+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|1   |ab& |
+----+----+
|2   |efg |
+----+----+
```

output

```
+----+----+
|col1|col3|
+----+----+
|1   |ab  |
+----+----+
|2   |efg |
+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`regexp_replace()`** function in spark.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+----+----+
#|col1|col2|
#+----+----+
#|   1| ab&|
#|   2| efg|
#+----+----+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("col3",regexp_replace("col2",'[^A-Za-z0-9]','')).show()
#+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|
#+----+----+----+
#|   1| ab&|  ab|
#|   2| efg| efg|
#+----+----+----+
```